# overwriting on excel files using java jxl

Tags: java, excel, shortest-path, jxl

I made a programme that calculates shortest paths using some data contained in an excel file.

The programme reads all the data in this file to create nodes. if the users input two values, then this programmes searches for the shortest path and returns it.

Now I want the users to be able to add / remove new data to this file. By doing this, they're adding new 'links' or removing existing links.  and the users would be able to see the changes they are making on the shortest path result.

However, I found out that most of the example codes on writing on an excel file is to create a new excel file, and copy whatever was in the original file.

I was wondering if there's any way to modify an existing excel file WITHOUT creating a copy of that file. I actually want the original excel file to change itself. because there are various methods (shortest path method) I've created to work with that exact file.

Any help or example codes would be great. Thanks.